# Detecting which field was actually modified

Tags: angularjs

I created a simple form which uses Angular JS for validation. The form has a Save and Modify button. If a user hits the modify button, it allows them to make changes to their inputs/fields. Another cool thing is that if something is actually modified, it will go ahead remain highlighted orange (so that a user knows which part of the form was modified) but if nothing is modified then there is no border once you go away from the field. My question/new requirement is the following:
If suppose I went on to the name field, for example, I change it and then decide to go back to what it was written originally, then theoritcally there should be no orange highlight remaining on the field. How do I make that happen? So if I change the field from A to B but then change it back to A, no border should be there because I ended up not changing the value. I have no idea how to do this. Any suggestions/guidance/tutorials that can help me solve this would be greatly appreciated. I have a snippet of my code below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.8" data-require="angular.js@1.4.8"></script>
  <script>
    var app = angular.module("app", []);
    app.controller("ctrl", function($scope) {


    });
  </script>
  <style>
    .someCSS {
      border: 5px solid orange;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">

  <form name="custForm">
    Name:
    <input id="name" ng-class="{someCSS: custForm.name.$dirty}" ng-model="someModel.name" />
    <br> email:(change some value)
    <input id="email2" name="email2" ng-class="{someCSS: custForm.email2.$dirty}" ng-model="someModel.email2" />

  </form>
  Touched:{{custForm.name.$touched}}
  <br> dirty:{{custForm.email2.$dirty}}
  <br>

</body>
```

Comment: Use the [ngFormController.$setUntouched method](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController#$setUntouched).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had a similar case - but even added an undo button. When populating the model for the first time, we stored a side-copy (use $angular.copy for a deep copy). Then when a field changed, the directive looked at the old value compared with the new value. E.G. `<input ng-class="{highlight-orange:old.name !== new.name}" />`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

      app.service('mySvc', function() {
        this.getData = function() {
          return { firstName:'Jack', lastName:'Sparrow' };
        }
      });

      app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, mySvc) {
        $scope.old = mySvc.getData();
        $scope.new = angular.copy($scope.old);
      });
    </script>
    <style>
      .different { color: red; }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
      <p>Name : <input type="text" ng-model="new.firstName" ng-class="{different:new.firstName !== old.firstName}"></p>
      <h1>Hello {{(new.firstName === old.firstName) ? 'Good, old' : 'Happy, new'}} {{new.firstName}}</h1>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Copy the code above into a file then load it into your browser.

Comment: Hi Paurian,Would it be possible that you share the code you wrote that shows this? (Or snippets/demo)?

Comment: Answer has been modified to show a code example. Let me know if this was useful.